# can't find syntax highlighting for offlineimaprc

Tags: syntax-highlighting

i can't find any syntax highlighting for offlineimaprc files.

Because of vim has normally for everything syntax highlighting (even for esoteric programming languages!), this makes me wondering.

Did i just failed to notice sth obvious or has vim really no syntax highlighting for offlineimaprc files?

Comment: The first result when googling "offlineimaprc vim" is a [github project](https://github.com/hrother/offlineimaprc.vim) that provides "Syntax highlighting offlineimap configuration file". I haven't tried it, but it seems worth looking at.

Comment: lol, duckduckgo.com didn't show me that result in the first 4 pages. Thanks anyways, it works. Would you consider to write your comment again as answer? Then i can mark it as solved.

Comment: Cool, glad it works. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [github project](https://github.com/hrother/offlineimaprc.vim) called offlineimaprc.vim that provides "Syntax highlighting offlineimap configuration file". I haven't tried it, but @toogley reported in a comment above that it works.